# Sort a marix by timestamp

Tags: bash, sorting

I am not sure if that applicable but I need to arrange and sort below output by timestamp below in column 2 under From , the newer should be on first line and the older on last line, what is needed is to keep the time format as it is, only I need to arrange by date

```
COUNT     FROM             TO
97        Oct 10 10:00:56  Oct 10 10:18:35
9         Mar 10 10:02:09  Oct 10 10:02:55
768       Oct 10 10:01:09  Oct 10 10:18:24
764       Oct 10 10:00:53  Oct 10 10:18:24
33        Oct 10 10:18:35  Oct 10 10:18:39
306       May 10 10:00:52  Oct 10 10:21:20
3         Oct 10 10:00:52  Oct 10 10:00:52
3         Oct 12 15:33:26  Nov 2 03:30:06
2         Oct 17 09:16:53  Oct 17 09:17:05
18        Nov 2 00:07:24   Nov 2 01:03:13
11        Oct 10 10:00:52  Oct 10 10:00:56
10095     Jun 10 10:00:52  Oct 10 10:18:24
10        Oct 10 10:18:40  Oct 10 10:18:45
1         Nov 2 03:21:32   Nov 2 03:21:32
1         Feb 2 01:31:53   Nov 2 01:31:53
1         Aug 2 03:26:24   Nov 2 03:26:24
1         Nov 2 03:21:32   Nov 2 03:21:32
1         Oct 10 10:18:05  Oct 10 10:18:05
1         Oct 17 09:16:52  Oct 17 09:16:52
1         Jan 10 10:02:55  Oct 10 10:02:55
1         Nov 2 23:24:09   Nov 2 23:29:09
1         Oct 10 10:00:52  Oct 10 10:00:52
1         Oct 10 10:00:53  Oct 10 10:00:53
1         Nov 2 03:22:22   Nov 2 03:22:22
1         Apr 2 06:41:29   Nov 2 06:41:29
```

The output should be with the same header with below as first line

```
1         Nov 2 23:24:09   Nov 2 23:29:09
```

, and below as the last line.

```
1         Jan 10 10:02:55  Oct 10 10:02:55
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `man sort` and you will see that you can sort by columns using the `-k` option.

This option supports a column number, and optional sort method.

For your case this might work:

```
sort -k2Mr -k3nr -k4r file.txt
```

`-k2Mr` do month sort on column two and reverse it.
`-k3nr` do numeric sort on column three and reverse it.
`-k4r` sort on column four and reverse it.

Comment: to keep the header, you could use the following functions before your `sort` call : `head -1 file.txt && tail -n +2 file.txt | sort -k2Mr -k3nr -k4nr` (or, if you want to only input the file name once : `file="file.txt" && head -1 $file && tail -n +2 $file | sort -k2Mr -k3nr -k4nr`)

Comment: `-k4nr` does not work properly on timestamps. `1         Oct 10 10:00:53  Oct 10 10:00:53
1         Oct 10 10:18:05  Oct 10 10:18:05
33        Oct 10 10:18:35  Oct 10 10:18:39
3         Oct 10 10:00:52  Oct 10 10:00:52
`

Comment: yes it didn't work here as well .. i am not sure i am trying other flags/args ...

Comment: @mshafey You might just be able to drop the numeric sort as the `hh:mm:ss` is padded: `sort -k2Mr -k3nr -k4r file.txt`

Comment: fine, its fine now with all -k but in numbers only column 3 and column 4 but how to finalize 2 column the months one Dec/Nov/Oct ....

Comment: @mshafey I don't think there is support for month sort with aix sort. One can
however use awk or similar to parse the date, then sort the output. And remove
the column again.

Comment: i think we can add jan feb mar . etc in a file and sort reference to that file ... but i am still trying that ... any help would be appreciated